# Disable Google Analytics when "Do Not Track" and "Global Privacy control is present"

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to disable google analytics if one or both of these features is present and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Adding this to a gtag variable that I could then use to disable my scripts

```
function() {
  var gpcHeader = response.headers.get('Sec-GPC');
  if (
    (gpcHeader === '1' || (navigator.globalPrivacyControl && navigator.globalPrivacyControl == '1')) ||
    (window.doNotTrack && window.doNotTrack == '1') ||
    (navigator.doNotTrack && (navigator.doNotTrack == 'yes' || navigator.doNotTrack == '1')) ||
    (navigator.msDoNotTrack && navigator.msDoNotTrack == '1') ||
    (window.external && ('msTrackingProtectionEnabled' in window.external) && window.external.msTrackingProtectionEnabled())
  ) {
    return "1";
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the Consent configuration changes they have made in Google Tag Manager? https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/10718549?hl=en